# How do I stop my components from showing when target image removed when using Vuforia?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am creating an AR business card that when target image found renders my game object (say a rotating cube). However when the target image is lost the object still remains even though I don't have extended tracking on. How do I stop this from happening?

I have tried making the front target image and the back target image come from different databases. I have tried using separate AR cameras. Nothing works

Figured it has to do with default-trackable-event-handler script but I don't know what to change and the renders are already supposed to be conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your GameObjects as a child of your Image target.

So while the image target found your GameObjects will be shown and while Image Target lost your GameObjects will be removed also

hope this helps...